# Can I push a local (CI) docker image to cluster using kubectl in CI?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, kubectl

I am using a CI and have built a Docker Image. I want to pass the image built in the CI to kubectl to take and place it in the cluster I have specified by my kubeconfig. This is as opposed to having the cluster reach out to a registry like dockerhub to retrieve the image. Is this possible?

So far I cannot get this to work and I am thinking I will be forced to create a secret on my cluster to just use my private docker repo. I would like to exhaust my options to not have to use any registry. Also as an alternative I already login to docker on my CI and would like to ideally only have to use those credentials once.

I thought setting the ImagePullPolicy on my deployment might do it but I think it is referring to the cluster context. Which makes me wonder if there is some other way to add an image to my cluster with something like a kubectl create image.

Maybe I am just doing something obvious wrong?

Here is my deploy script on my CI

```
docker build -t <DOCKERID>/<PROJECT>:latest -t <DOCKERID>/<PROJECT>:$GIT_SHA -f ./<DIR>/Dockerfile ./<DIR>
docker push <DOCKERID>/<PROJECT>:latest
docker push <DOCKERID>/<PROJECT>:$GIT_SHA

kubectl --kubeconfig=$HOME/.kube/config apply -f k8s
kubectl --kubeconfig=$HOME/.kube/config set image deployment/<DEPLOYMENT NAME> <CONTAINER NAME>=<DOCKERID>/<PROJECT>:$SHA
```

And this Dockerfile:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <deployment name>
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: <CONTAINER NAME>
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: <CONTAINER NAME>
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: <CONTAINER NAME>
          image: <DOCKERID>/<PROJECT>
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: <PORT>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to pass the image [...] to kubectl to take and place it in the cluster [...] as opposed to having the cluster reach out to a registry like dockerhub to retrieve the image. Is this possible?

No.  Generally the only way an image gets into a cluster is by a node pulling an image named in a pod spec.  And even there "in the cluster" is a little vague; each node will have a different collection of images, based on which pods have ever run there and what's historically been cleaned up.

There are limited exceptions for developer-oriented single-node environments (you can `docker build` an image directly in a minikube VM, then set a pod to run it with `imagePullPolicy: Never`) but this wouldn't apply to a typical CI system.

> I would like to exhaust my options to not have to use any registry.

Kubernetes essentially requires a registry.  If you're using a managed Kubernetes from a public-cloud provider (EKS/GKE/AKS/...), there is probably a matching image registry offering you can use (ECR/GCR/ACR/...).

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this is the conclusion I think I will have to reach. 

I don't know how familiar you are with Kubernetes and Docker and their products but -- Does this proposition seem at all like a reasonable use case? As someone very new to CI/CD Docker and K8s this feels obviously useful, maybe even simple, but I would imagine since it feels that way there is something I am missing about architecting a CI/CD using these containerized systems...

Comment: The system I normally work with works fundamentally the way you describe: every commit results in a new image being automatically built and pushed to a repository, and then Deployments' `image:` get updated to the new tag (through a Helm chart).  The cluster nodes are configured with appropriate credentials to be able to pull from the repository.

Comment: Do you think Kubernetes would ever consider supporting an option similar to 'kubectl set image' along the lines of 'kubectl push image' or 'kubectl set image from=<here>' or is it out of scope or improper workflow sort of thing?

Comment: Since a cluster has multiple nodes, and not every node will be running every possible image, and nodes can be dynamically added and removed, you need some sort of place to keep the images: if a new node is created and gets a pod scheduled on it, it needs to be able to retrieve the image from somewhere.  I don't think Kubernetes would be especially motivated to reinvent that.

Comment: True, the scheduling new pods makes a lot of sense as to why you want something external and not based on a supplied image. So if I really want to do it I make a registry pod and a build pod or something like that.  I appreciate your time thank you for engaging !

Answer (score 0):

Preferred way in k8s setting is to update k8s definitions or helm chart values or kustomize values (whichever you are using) with image and its sha256 digest that needs to be deployed.

Using sha256 digest is preferable to tags in production since docker image tags are mutable.

Next, instead of using kubectl from CI/CD it's preferred to use a GitOps tool - either Argo or Flux on the k8s side to pull the correct images based on definitions in Git.

There you need some sort of system to route and manage images - which one should go to which environment. Here is my article with an example how it can be achieved (this one is using my tool): https://itnext.io/building-kubernetes-cicd-pipeline-with-github-actions-argocd-and-reliza-hub-e7120b9be870

Comment: Thanks I'll maybe look at this in the future but it is out of my current workflow of git repo > CI for test, build, deploy > web service. I would have to learn new tools you discuss here and while that might be the better way to do it I am keeping it simple at this time.